# Question about Schengen visa

Tags: schengen

I am not an EU passport holder, but currently working in Ireland. I have a GNIB card which is going be up for renewal on the 3rd o January 2020. I am planning to go to France on September 27-October 3 this year which falls just in time within the 3 month allowance before expiration the Schenghen visa requires.

The question is, if the Embassy in France would grant me a 6 month Schengen visa, can I still go to other countries in the EU after October 3 using the same visa that France would grant?

Comment: **Visa C** is based on the 90/180 rule. **Visa D** is for longer periods and is a **national** visa. During the time of a Visa D, travel to **other** Schengen Countries are permitted based on the 90/180 rule while inside those countries.

Answer (score 1):

> If the Embassy in France would grant me a 6 month schengen visa, can I still go to other countries in the EU after October 3 using the same visa that france would grant?

Yes (subject of course to the other conditions of short-term travel to the Schengen area).  It strikes me as unlikely, however, that France will give you a visa valid beyond the expiration of your residence permit.

(The previous version of this answer was based on a misreading of the question.)

Comment: his GNIB card needs renewal, his passport is not meantioned.

Comment: @MarkJohnson I see. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: but after oct 3, the gnib is now within the 3 month expiration period. will i still be permitted to go inside other schengen countries using the visa from france? or will i be stopped in the airport?

Comment: @anonIreland as far as I'm aware, the validity of the GNIB is only relevant to the visa application, not to the actual trip.